# QModbusTcpClient cant connect to PLC

Tags: qt, modbus, plc

Im trying to connect to PLC device. I set all configuration in device correct, I was sucessfull connected and tested communication between PC and PLC device by ModbusSlave software.

My QT code is:

```
    PLC = new QModbusTcpClient();
    m_port = 502;
    m_host = "10.100.101.2"; //PLC IP
    PLC->setConnectionParameter(QModbusDevice::NetworkPortParameter, this->m_port);
    PLC->setConnectionParameter(QModbusDevice::NetworkAddressParameter, this->m_host);
    PLC->setTimeout(5000);
    PLC->setNumberOfRetries(10);

    qDebug()<<"State: " << PLC->state();

    qDebug()<<"Try to connect...";
    if(!PLC->connectDevice()){
        qDebug()<<"Not connected to PLC: " << PLC->errorString();

    }
    else{
        qDebug()<<"State: " << PLC->state();

        while(PLC->state()!=QModbusDevice::ConnectedState){
        QThread::msleep(5);
        }
        qDebug()<<"Connection to PLC succesed" << PLC->state();
        emit PLCConnected();
    }
```

The output is:

State:  QModbusDevice::UnconnectedState
Try to connect...
State:  QModbusDevice::ConnectingState

Answer (score 0):

first, what does PLC->connectDevice() do?

second, you can not wait for connection in the same thread, just subscribe to QModbusDevice::stateChanged signal and look for state changes

Comment: Thanks, subscribing this signals against waiting in the loop solved the problem.